# Remove Compare from Product List in Magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-list, magento2.1.6, compare

I need to delete the compare button from product list but I don't know how to to do it in Magento 2.1.6.
[image]

Under [vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/

I deleted the following in list.phtml:

```
<?php
   $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                                ?>
   <a href="#" class="action tocompare" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
      aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
      data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
       role="button">
       <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('<i class="fa fa-refresh"> </i>') ?>
   </a>
```

and deleted the following in listing.phtml

```
. '<a href="' . $block->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) . '" class="action tocompare">'
. '<span>' . __('Add to Compare') . '</span></a>
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Check in layout file  Under [vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Comment: do not delete the code, use XML to remove

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I thought that catalog_category_vie‌​w.xml is for Product Detail Page, no? I already removed the button in that page but in the product list (widget?), the button is still there.

Comment: @RamaChandran the solution there doesn't seem to work in 2.1.6 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you  was ***try to comment the code on  wrong phtml.***,So,you should enable the template hind from admin and ***find out exact phtml for this section*** and then the **commenting /delete the code**

```
. '<a href="' . $block->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) . '" class="action tocompare">'
. '<span>' . __('Add to Compare') . '</span></a>
```

Also, Then you Should to flush cache using `bin/magento cache:flush` or delete all files from ***`magentoApplicationDir/var/view_procescced`***

Comment: My bad. You were right, I was modifying the wrong phtml.

Answer (score 8):

Update your **extended catalog_category_view.xml** file and Find it at your extended theme path

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

To remove compare from listing Page use this  code

```
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
```

I hope this will help you if not then let me know

Thanks

Comment: It didn't work in product list. I already removed the compare button in Product detail page. But in the product list, it is still there.

Comment: run upgrade/deploy/cache commands once